# Problems with jquery mobile, functions not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, mobile

I need some help with a jqueryMobile app.

http://www.mandinker.com/proyects_vip_dev/app-llarjove/

1. In this link you'll find some boxes, click on the box named "CALENDARIO".
2. Okey, everything works, then press the dropfooter and go to "INICIO".
3. Do again the first step, go to "CALENDARIO", and tada, error!

Here's the error:

> TypeError: calendario is not a function
>       ...".ui-page-active .calendario").size()){calendario();$(
>       "#datepicker" ).datepicke...

And here is the relevant source code:

```
$(document).delegate('.ui-page-active', 'pageshow', function () {
    if($(".ui-page-active .calendario").size()){
       calendario();
       $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    }   
});

function makecalendar(){    
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
}

function calendario(){
    makecalendar();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://llarjove.softonthecloud.net/calendar",
        data: {},
        error: function(){},
        success: function(data) {
            calendario=data;
            $(".calendario ul.ui-listview").html("");
            $("td").attr("class","ui-datepicker-unselectable");
            noticias=data.news;
            $.each(noticias,function(key,value){               
                tmp=value.fecha.split(" ");
                tmp=tmp[0].split("-");                               
                $("td[data-month="+(parseInt(tmp[1])-1)+"][data-year="+tmp[0]+"] > a").filter(function(){ 
            tmp[2]=tmp[2].replace(/^0+/, "");                       
        if($(this).text()==parseInt(tmp[2])){                       
            return $(this).text()==parseInt(tmp[2]);
        };    
        }).css({"background":"#00cae8","color":"white"}).attr("href","./calenItem.html?fecha='"+value.fecha+"'").on("click",function(){window.location.href = "./calenItem.html?fecha='"+encodeURIComponent(value.fecha)+"'";});
            });
        },
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    });
    setInterval(function(){
        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").height($(window).height()-$(".ui-header").height()-120);
    },300);
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Is calendario function in the $(document).ready(function() { ..}); ?

Comment: Or you have to put your functions in the delegate function also.

Comment: The functions are out of the delegate and the $(document).ready(); And datepicker also gives me an error, but datepicker is another .js, so I need something to reload my .js again when the app gives me an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see your POST request only executes the first time you click on "CALENDARIO".
I suggest you investigate 2 possibilities:

1. Your event handler is not firing, this usually happens on dynamical created content. To fix it add an event listener to the parent.
2. Make sure that when creating dynamic content you are replacing, not duplicating with the same ID because the event handler will only fire on the first ID it finds in the HTML tree

UPDATE:
I had a good look at your code and I'll point 2 things that I think are strange and give you trouble.

I suggest you remove from `$(document).delegate()`

```
//I think this condition is always true on return or refresh and kills your flow
$( '.ui-page' ).not( '.ui-page-active' ).remove();
```

and

```
if (recarga) {
    location.reload();
    recarga=false;
};
```

also move `$(document).delegate()` function after `$(document).ready()`

Comment: I was looking the application, and the problem is it don't load the functions properly.

So, I can't execute the non-existent functions.